# Getting YOUR total clicks on a button through php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

What i'm exactly trying do is count the person who clicked that button's total clicks not the overall total of all the members combined clicks., but just your clicks alone on that button.

Whenever a person clicks on a specific button it should log there clicks alone. I'm trying to figure out how to do exactly do that. I'm clueless at the moment, how to exactly do that. Identity users through a uniqueid through mysql.

I already know how to get the total clicks of the overall members and here's the code for that

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['clicks']) ) { 
    incrementClickCount();
}

function getClickCount()
{
    return (int)file_get_contents("count.txt");
}

function incrementClickCount()
{
    $count = getClickCount() + 1;
    file_put_contents("count.txt", $count);
}
?>
```

Could someone give me a idea, how to achieve that exactly?

Comment: does your users have a unique id? use that. just get the id of the currently logged in user

Comment: Yes they have a unique id

Comment: If you wish to count the clicks to a button that does not load a page, you will need to implement this on the client and then pass it to the server.

Comment: I'm not sure but can you have an onClick function that will increment a javascript variable (no need to make php count it as of now)? Then pass it into ajax to do whatever you want from there, if you want to put it into a database as Hirsh said. If you need to be picky about the user have some PHP if($_SESSION['id']==$req_id) or something.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a mySQL server that already gives users a unique identity basically create a second field in the users table 'count' and then increment the 'count' variable corresponding to the user that clicked the button.